# Determining syntax group type from output of 'syn list' (doesn't appear to work for regions)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, functions

Why does the output of `syn list` not include `region` in the syntax group definition line, like it does for 'match' type groups? What is the meaning of the `xxx` in that line?

I've got a vim 8.0 function that accepts a syntax group name, parses the output of `syn list` for that group, then clears and redefines that syntax group with a minor tweak (in this case, it is toggling the conceal arg). The final step requires executing `syn match`, `syn region`, etc.. and so requires determination of the specified group's type.

As I've stated above, the group type is not provided for regions, so before I just work around this by grepping for the required and unique `start` and `end` args in order to determine group type, I thought I'd ask whether anyone knows why this discrepancy exists. Is it a bug? Is there some other (better) way to grokk syntax group type from `syn list` output?